# Display screen in VisualStudio like in Eclipce

Tags: visual-studio

In eclipse I have a window called "Display" where I can run functions in debugger mode.
Do I have some thing like that in VisualStudio ?

If i do how it called and how to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx). You can type required methods and execute them there when debugging.